# Xubuntu 14.04 bluetooth headphones problem

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

This morning I installed Xubuntu 14.04 with Xfce 4.12 and everything works fine but my bluetooth headphones system. Before I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked correctly.

Reading on the web, I managed to install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
and to insert the following line into `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

but nothing really changed.

The headphones are seen from my laptop, but I cannot start streaming audio (it is not available as option in `pavucontrol`).

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved the problem. I managed to "reset" manually the headphones by long pressing a button. At this point, Ubuntu was not pairing anymore automatically the headphones and I was able to restart a "new device connection".

So, it was not Ubuntu fault. :)